# How to use Bluetooth in Docker Containers on Raspberry Pi 4 without net=host Flag?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, bluetooth, raspberry-pi4

I use a Rasperry Pi 4 with Raspberry Pi OS and docker compose. In my compose I have several containers and also several networks. I want to use the embedded Bluetooth in one of the containers. Since the corresponding container is connected to multiple networks, I can not use `network_mode: host`.

I can confirm that `docker run --net=host --privileged -i -t ubuntu /bin/bash` works and creates me a container by which I can also use Bluetooth (tested with hcitool lescan). But how can I do this without using `network_mode: host` (or `--net=host`)?